# cassandra source connector and kafka - what if u have just bigint epoch timestamp?

Tags: cassandra, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

```
kafka-connect: kafka-connect-cassandra-1.2.1-2.1.0-all.jar
```

My data inside cassandra are timestamped with epoch time saved as bigint. I want to retrieve those data into kafka topic using incremental mode inside kafka connect. According to spec - I need to have Timestamp,Timeuuid,Token field to be able to handle this.

My initial idea is that eventually, I could use `TimestampConverter$Value` inside worker configuration but after all, I guess it is not the way. Time conversion works with a bulk pooling. With incremental mode I got:

```
Codec not found for requested operation: [bigint <-> java.util.Date]
```

which might be logical as before u do transformation u somehow need to pool data.

Question is:

> is there any way to connect kafka to cassandra with incremental mode
>   in such a configuration where the only timestamp field is bigint that
>   consist epoch and there is no Timeuuid||Timestamp field available?

Thank You 
greetings Kris